# How to switch tabs and change css class on click using Angular2?

Tags: javascript, html, css, typescript, angular

On clicking on one tab i want to make the class `tab-active` and remove it from the other and vice versa. The HTML code on which I want to implement this is :-

```
<div class="tab-change-login">
    <ul class="un-styled tab-ul">
        <li class="tab-active" data-login="signin-area">SIGN IN</li>
        <li data-login="signup-area">SIGN UP</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

How do I write a onClick function to switch between 2 tabs usiing angular2

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use class binding like:

```
@Component({
  selector: '...',
  template: `
    <div class="tab-change-login">
        <ul class="un-styled tab-ul">
            <li [class.tab-active]="activeTabName == 'signin-area'" 
                data-login="signin-area"
                (click)="activeTabName = 'signin-area'">SIGN IN</li>
            <li [class.tab-active]="activeTabName == 'signup-area'" 
                data-login="signup-area"
                (click)="activeTabName = 'signup-area'">SIGN UP</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
`})
export class MyComponennt {
  activeTabName = 'signup-area';
}
```

There are other ways like [ngClass](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/common/NgClass-directive.html)

Comment: Hi, thanks that worked but now if I have to hide a particular portion depending on which tab is selected will using ngIf to check the `activeTabName` value and hide/unhide accordingly work?

Comment: Sure `ngIf` or `ngSwitch` https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/common/NgSwitch-directive.html